# Global variable is not so global in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript and going through [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) tutorial on jQuery's website.

In following example

```
    // A function being attached to an object at runtime
    var myName = "the global object";
    var sayHello = function ()
    {
        console.log("Hi! My name is " + this.myName);
    };
    var myObject = {
        myName: "Rebecca"
    };
    var secondObject = {
        myName: "Colin"
    };

    myObject.sayHello = sayHello;
    secondObject.sayHello = sayHello;

    sayHello();              // "Hi! My name is the global object"
    myObject.sayHello();     // "Hi! My name is Rebecca"
    secondObject.sayHello(); // "Hi! My name is Colin"
```

I don't see expected output when `sayHello()` is invoked. Instead variable is `undefined`. But if I define global variable by assigning it to `window.myName` it works.

I'm using Chrome Version 25.0.1364.152 m.

Is tutorial incorrect or am I missing something ?

Full HTML is here: http://pastebin.com/4M27vDB4

**UPDATE**: Accepted answer explains what happened. I also want to mention possible solution - declaring global variable above without `var`. Because of following:

> Furthermore, variables that are declared inside a function without the
>   var keyword are not local to the function — JavaScript will traverse
>   the scope chain all the way up to the window scope to find where the
>   variable was previously defined. If the variable wasn't previously
>   defined, it will be defined in the global scope, which can have
>   unexpected consequences.

Comment: Works here (Chrome 25). How are you running your code?

Comment: This seems to work fine on my Chrome 25

Comment: Maybe you have put this code inside `$(function() { ... });` closure? In this case context inside it will not be `window` and you will get `undefined` as you describe.

Comment: sounds like you are putting that sample code inside a function body, which means the first "var myName" creates a local variable to that function instead. If you use window.myName, you are explicitely assigning to global scope.

Comment: right, so it's like we said, your "var MyName" assignment is inside a function: "$(document).ready(function () { ... });"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have put this code inside

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    // ...
});
```

closure. In this case context inside it will not be `window` (it will be `document` object) and you will get `undefined` as you describe.

Answer (score 3):

in your program you have used `this.myName`. `this` keyword is used to point current object. when you call only `sayHello()` then in that case "this" means "window" because default current object is window. Now you have not defined `window.myName` then it will give "undefined".